# New process for Windows by Node.js (Create .pdf file)

Tags: windows, node.js, cmd, pdf

Пытаюсь создать файл pdf с помощью утилиты wkhtmltopdf.

Проблема: неверно передаю команду в cmd (удаляются слеши "\")

**Вопрос: Как правильно передать команду? Пробовал экранировать, видимо неправильно делаю.**

(Ниже привожу код исполняемого файла)

```
"use strict";//http://jsman.ru/express/
var http = require('http'),
  fs = require('fs'),
  url = require('url'),
  port = 8080,
  host = '127.0.0.1',
  express = require('express'),
  cmd = require('node-cmd'),
  path = require('path'),
  app = express();
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.get('/', function(req, res){res.send(200, "Hello, World")});
app.get('/pdf', function(req, res){
  cmd.get(
    'cd "C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin" | wkhtmltopdf www.yandex.ru C:\Users\amstel\Desktop\yandex.pdf',
    function(data, err, stderr){
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Done\n',data)
      } else {
        console.log('Error\n', err)
      }
    }
  );
})

var server = app.listen(port, host);
console.log("Express server running on http://%s:%s", host, port);
```

Результат выполнения данного кода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Иллюстрация 2 (ввод двух комманд сразу не работает):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы говорите, что пробовали экранировать. Как именно пробовали? Надо каждый ` \ ` заменить на ` \\ `.

Comment: @Yaant Пробую вводить это в cmd с клавиатуры (см. иллюстрацию 2) - в первом варианте не сработало (когда ввожу две команды, разделенные " | ", работает только во втором случае, если их вводить поочереди)

Comment: Во-первых, Вам тут нужен не `|`, а `&`, а во-вторых, скорее всего, не нужно даже это, попробуйте выполнить программу сразу, без `cd`, просто с указанием полного пути: `C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf www.yandex.ru C:\\Users\amstel\\Desktop\\yandex.pdf` (Тем более, что с `cd` возникнут сюрпризы, если вдруг программа находится на другом логическом диске.)

Comment: **Заработало!)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, В JavaScript обратный слэш (`\`) используется для экранирования специальных символов. Для того, чтобы добавить этот символ в строку его тоже нужно экранировать. Иными словами в строках вместо `\` вам стоит использовать `\\`. Вот так:

```
var p = 'C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin';
```

Во-вторых, если в командной строке Windows, то вместо оператора `|` нужно использовать `&&`. Вот так:

```
var cmd = 'cd "C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin" && wkhtmltopdf www.yandex.ru C:\\out.pdf'
```

Более того, вместо вызова двух команд в консоли, вы вполне можете обойтись одной:

```
var cmd = '"C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf" www.yandex.ru C:\\out.pdf';
```

Comment: **Ок, спасибо!**